# How to handle concurrency in a nestjs API?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a question when using performance testing at the time of multiple requests to 1 API concurrently. Here I use **nestjs** and **sequelize** as orm. In the case like below, I send a block with *20 concurrent requests* to the API */languages*. here I attach a **transaction** and let it **sleep for 3s**, then return the result. when 20 requests come to api /languages, *it gathers 5 requests in 1 block and process*, then it returns the result. You can check the picture below. it takes **12s to process a block of 20 requests**. The problem here is that I do not understand the processing mechanism here?, please explain to me. thank you guys. <3

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly the question but I read your code in this way: `for i that goes from 0 to 4` you `await test` (suppose that i = 0). test, `for i that goes from 0 to 19` fills `callRef`, an array of promises. Then you pass this array to `Promise.all` that resolves all the promises and finally enter into then. After this, the code returns to `await test`, print TEST ... and pass to next iteration.

Comment: I don't think it is really a real "concurrent" event being simulated but, I think using transaction is already a good approach.
If you seeking another approach, you can always use Redis (INCR) since its single-thread.

Comment: @RichiePermana I am trying to simulate a concurrency case. where is it not correct, please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Using transaction is a good approach when dealing with concurrent events.

But if you looking for another method, I guess you can use Redis's Increment key ([Read More](https://redis.io/commands/INCR)) and use its callback. Since it is single-threaded, I'm sure you have to no worry about anything.

Anyway, you can always take its cute tutorial **[here](https://try.redis.io/)**.